# how to host a fastAPI on your local machine to be accessed by other machines

Tags: python, fastapi

I have created an API using fastAPI and now im wondering if i can access  this API from other machines on the same local network and when i try to open API docs page they dont open from other machines so im wondering if theres a way i can make my api accessible to other users and whether i can use the API from virtual machine on the same local machine.

I tried using a virtual machine and it couldnt open the API

Comment: You'll have to start uvicorn and bind it to a different host than 127.0.0.1 - if you're running in a VM you'll either have to forward the ports from your host (if running in NAT mode) or run in network bridge mode and bind to the network interface (and not loopback).